# Charting with Dygraphs: Data sampling depending on zoom

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Although Dygraphs performs very well compared to other solution, when viewing more and more data points, the performance inevitably slows.

I already have all my data loaded locally. Is there a way for Dygraphs to intelligently display a lower resolution (in terms of number of data points) and then show more on zoom?

Comment: Perusing the documentation, this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Indeed, on occasion I've discovered numerous additional undocumented features but unfortunately on this occasion this doesn't appear to be the case......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in facility, but it is possible. See this thread for an example of one user who pulled it off: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dygraphs-users/kgdNdt1A0dk

Comment: Is there documentation on *how* to use this? Because as a demo it looks neat, but honestly I can't figure out how to plug my own data.

Comment: How to use it is explained in detail here: http://kaliatech.github.io/dygraphs-dynamiczooming-example/example1.html