# Loading Detailed data on Zoom in Dygraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, zooming, dygraphs

I am using dygraphs.js to show a chart. 
Initially only a subset of the entire data is shown and on zooming in more detailed data is loaded.

I make ajax call to server in the ZoomCallback to get detailed data and then again intialize the graph object and zoom to the dateWindow. I am facing problem with this zoom functionality. The problem is the zoom works for the first time and the detailed data is seen but if I again zoom the zoomed data, the minX and maxX of the zoom call back are not captured correctly and hence my data load from server fails and nothing is seen the graph

Here is my javascript code

```
function drawChart(data, myMinX, myMaxX) {
var dateWindow = null;
var drawPoints = $('#draw-points').prop('checked');
if (myMinX != undefined || myMinX != null)
    dateWindow = [myMinX, myMaxX];

$("#myMinX").val("");
$("#myMaxX").val("");
$("#isZoomed").val(false);

g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("linechart_material"),
                    data,
                    {
                        showRangeSelector: false,
                        connectSeparatedPoints: true,
                        drawPoints: drawPoints,
                        zoomCallback: function (minX, maxX, yRanges) {


                                console.log("Zoomed to [", minX, ", ", maxX, "] -> Y-Range: ", yRanges[0]);
                                $("#isZoomed").val(true);
                                $("#myMinX").val(minX);
                                $("#myMaxX").val(maxX);

                                OnSubmit(null);

                        },
                        pointSize: 5,
                        highlightCircleSize: 10,
                        series: {
                            Original: {
                                drawPointCallback: pointShape,
                                drawHighlightPointCallback: pointShape
                            },
                            Simplified: {
                                drawPointCallback: pointShape,
                                drawHighlightPointCallback: pointShape
                            }
                        },
                        legend: 'always',
                        //colors: ["#A0354C", "#5B9833"]
                        colors: ["#63A0D7", "#ED7D31"],
                        dateWindow: dateWindow
                    });

    var height = $('#linechart_material').height();
    var width = $('#linechart_material').width();
    $('#height').val(height);
    $('#width').val(width);

}



 function OnSubmit(evt) {

 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: actionUrl,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {

            if (result != undefined && result != '') {
                session_data = result.Data;

                drawChart(result.Data, minX, maxX)

         }
            $("#isZoomed").val(false);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {


        }
    });

}
```

Here are the minX and maxX logged in the console during first zoom and then again zooming on the zoomed graph respectively
[image: Zoom Range]

Please Let me know If I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: Let me know if more details are required!

Comment: Is this the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397655/charting-with-dygraphs-data-sampling-depending-on-zoom)?

Comment: @danvk :  It seems similar but frankly speaking I could not follow the flow of how it was achieved in the link you posted in that question.. Is there any simpler explanation. I am a newbie to this

Comment: @danvk I looked into the example you shared. It seems that in that example the detailed data for the zoomed window is generated on the client side itself in the JGS.ServerDataSimulator.js file. Similar behaviour works for us. if we set new data in the zoomcallback it works fine. The problem occurs only when I am trying to bring in data making a ajax call. When trying to zoom for the second time after the ajax call, the values of minX and maxX in the callback are very strange, they dont even seem to be numbers ( refer screencap above). If you have seen such behaviour please let me know!